# Mysql import transforms timestamp null values to 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mysqlimport

I have some text file -generated periodically- which contains sql rows to be inserted to mysql using mysqlimport. One of the columns has Null value, and this column in the database is a datetime field, with default value set to Null. However after running mysql import, I got the value 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in this column, so how can I get rid of this? I want the column value to be Null as inserted.

**Edit**:
Notes:

1) When inserting a row directly using INSERT statement, this problem doesn't occur and the column value is set to NULL normally, so this has something to do with `mysqlimport`

2) I use this mysqlimport: `mysqlimport -u root -p<password> -h localhost --columns='<columns_orders>' --local --fields-terminated-by=',' <db_name> <file_path>`

3) Sample of one row in the data file: `5964,45,0,0,NULL,45,5,8,67869,67848,65142,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,19`

4) The datetime column is rails timestamp `created_at` that is created via   a rails migration.

Comment: How about setting to NULL all the rows concerned (which have 000....000 in their datetimefield) ? Oh well missread the question - u need it before.

Comment: The preferred method to show a datetime column empty is storing it into `0000-00-00 00:00:00` format. That's how most of the developers do it, I'm not sure why you want to change it.

Comment: @Imran really? I've never heard of any developer that I know doing that... always stored as NULL.

Comment: I know this is a little too obvious, but does the column allow NULL? Also, set the default value as NULL. Probably won't fix it, but worth a shot.

Comment: Does your column have a `DEFAULT NULL` attribute? I think you can do something like that, but I'm not positive.

Comment: @KevinNagurski yes the column allow null

Comment: @McAdam331 yes its default value is NULL

Comment: What does the import look like?

Comment: @KevinNagurski `mysqlimport -u root -p<password> -h localhost --columns='<columns_orders>' --local --fields-terminated-by=',' <db_name> <file_path>`

Comment: What about a sample of the data?

Comment: @KevinNagurski sample of one record: `5964,45,0,0,NULL,45,5,8,67869,67848,65142,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,19`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If table definition allows null and defaults to NULL and your source data also contains \N then you should get NULL as expected. MySQL is not a reliable database server in many different ways, so I'd need your sources (at least some sample) to diagnostic the actual problem. May be empty string instead of \N.

Comment: sample of one record:
`5964,45,0,0,NULL,45,5,8,67869,67848,65142,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,19`

Comment: Please try with \N (null escape) instead of NULL. I'll confirm if the NULL string is considered NULL for MySQL.

Comment: There's also an important option that makes MySQL stop on casting errors. This invalid date MySQL accepts is really annoying, but in fact it should fail to import on any error.

Comment: It worked !! Writing \N instead of NULL did the trick! This means that NULL string was interpreted as undefined value and thus default zero value was inserted, which for datetime is 0000-00-00 00:00:00, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Actually NULL is an invalid date representation MySQL is silently transforming into 0000-00-00. It should fail, but using MySQL is only a choice to be considered when dealing with legacy systems and databases. One should always prefer PostgreSQL to MySQL for new software. Your import should croak on invalid data.

Answer (score 0):

There can be quick hack:

- For the time being change that datetime column's type to `VARCHAR` so that null values become empty strings.
- When import is complete change that column's type back to datetime and it'll give you the desired results :)

Comment: I generate the data file periodically, so I can't use this hack

Comment: Thats fine but this may help someone else with similar problem :)