# In Laravel application, mysql import transforms timestamp null values to 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, csv

In Laravel application I have a MySQL timestamp field **deleted_at** which was created for softDeletes and the default value is NULL. If the value is not NULL the Eloquent will not retrive the data. When I import CSV file the NULL value from source file becomes 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

I read [Mysql import transforms timestamp null values to 0000-00-00 00:00:00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462811/mysql-import-transforms-timestamp-null-values-to-0000-00-00-000000) and \N does not worked for me. I have many tables which I need to import periodically, so I really need to fix this. Please help.

Comment: How are you importing the data?

Comment: Follow the second answer from the link you have given. It might help.

Comment: I use import from phpMyAdmin and chose csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable strict mode in MySQL. Particularly, the mode name is STRICT_TRANS_TABLES . Open `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` (or the same file in Windows) find and comment out `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` there.

More information is here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict

Comment: I'm using xampp (mysql ver. 15.1 Distrib 10.1.16-MariaDB). I don't have any my.cnf file. In my.ini file does not exists STRICT_TRANS_TABLES. I'm reading https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/timestamp but can't fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should see your **config/database.php** file. This file contains the variable from where you can set the strict mode - On / Off.

Laravel now gives you the power to enable / disable mysql modes. With this new feature, Laravel now has the ability to do three things: Disable "strict" mode, returning to the <= 5.6 behavior; enable "strict" mode, setting it to the 5.7 behavior; or customizing exactly which modes are enabled.

The code in your file goes like this...

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true, // <----- This variable sets the strict mode.
        'engine' => null,
  ],
```

set this value to false if you want to disable the strict mode else make it true to enable the strict mode.
Hope this help you to solve your problem.

Comment: In database.php is: 'strict' => false.